# What are the risks of allowing an app the "Draw over other apps" permission?

Tags: security, permissions, android-12

There's an app I'd like to install on my phone (Android 12) that blocks access to distracting apps. It requires the "Draw over other apps" permission. This seems like a dangerous permission, and I'm trying to figure out *how* dangerous it is before I allow it.

- Does this permission allow the app to see what's being displayed by all other apps? Or does it only allow it to detect touch input?
- Does this permission allow it to draw over the on-screen keyboard, so that it can see what I type and potentially type for me? (This is my biggest concern)
- Are there any other security risks from allowing this permission?

EDIT: [This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/186491/so-if-draw-over-other-apps-is-a-bad-thing-why-are-so-many-people-wanting-to-ena) an [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/184044/does-draw-over-other-apps-permission-allow-the-app-the-see-the-content-of-the) both say that the permission does not grant the ability to see the content of the background app, so assuming those answers are still correct (they're both 4 years old), then that's one question answered.